# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table MyMovies has no column named _ReleaseDate

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this table in my database

```
  public static final String TABLE_MOVIES_NAME = "MyMovies";
  public static final String TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_ID = "_Id";
  public static final String TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_NAME = "_Name";
  public static final String TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DATE_ADDED = "_AddedDate";
  public static final String TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DATE_RELEASE = "_ReleaseDate";
  public static final String TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "_Description";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "????.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_NAME + "("
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DATE_RELEASE + "text not null, "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key, "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_NAME + " text not null, "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DATE_ADDED + " text not null, "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text not null);";
```

and I try to add some values(movies) into it `ContentValues values = 
_ReleaseDate=2013-06-18 _Id=0 _Name=a _AddedDate=2013-02-18 _Description=asfsgagafgadf`

and when i do insert `database.insertOrThrow(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_MOVIES_NAME, null, values);`

i get this error `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table MyMovies has no column named _ReleaseDate (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO MyMovies(_ReleaseDate,_Id,_Name,_AddedDate,_Description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)`
what did i do wrong?

Comment: You're missing a space here:

 + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DATE_RELEASE + "text not null, "

The column is likely _ReleaseDatetext.

Comment: Can you try removing '_' from your column names and change the _Id to '_id'? I think sqlite uses _id as primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_NAME + "("
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DATE_RELEASE + "text not null, "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key, "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_NAME + " text not null, "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DATE_ADDED + " text not null, "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text not null);";
```

to:

```
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_NAME + "("
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DATE_RELEASE + " text not null, "//Space added here.
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key, "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_NAME + " text not null, "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DATE_ADDED + " text not null, "
      + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text not null);";
```

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης Happens to the best of us :) SQL statements are easy to mess up when typing out like this.

Comment: That  SPPPAAACCEEEE... :3

Answer (score 0):

Add a space here :

```
  + TABLE_MOVIES_COLUMN_DATE_RELEASE + " text not null, "  // space before 'text'
```